# not found url when use persian/arabic slug in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, url, slug

database: mysql 
database Collation encode: 'utf8_general_ci' 
django version: last version
python version: 3.7.12

**Note** : It work well in local host but not working in real host

**Error :**

[image: The error]

**models.py :**

```
class blog(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,allow_unicode=True,unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return  f'title: {self.title}'
```

**Views.py :**

```
def blogViews(request,slug):
    if blog.objects.filter(slug=slug).count() > 0:
        post = blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
        context = {
            'post': post,
        }
        return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

**i tried these:**

**1-** change get_bytes_from_wsgi encode in django/core/handlers/wsgi.py

```
return value.encode('ISO-8859-1')
```

**to**

```
return value.encode('UTF-8')
```

**2-** django setings.py:

```
ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = True
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: I guess I have to change something on the host, because it works correctly on the local server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was my url regex**

**model.py** :

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class blog(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,allow_unicode=True,unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Optional
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return  f'title: {self.title}'
```

**urls.py** :

```
from django.urls import re_path


urlpatterns = [
    # the main problem was here
    re_path(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/?$', blogtagsViews),
    
]
```

**Views.py** :

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

def blogViews(request,slug):
    slug = unquote(slug)
    if blog.objects.filter(slug=slug).count() > 0:
        post = blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
        context = {
            'post': post,
        }
        return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hex D8AAD8B3D8AA, when decoded as UTF-8 is Arabic `تست` -- is that what you expected?

It looks like the string went through more than one encoding -- at least once to turn into `%D8%AA...` -- as if with PHP's `urlencode()`.

Then it seems to have gone through it again -- to get the `%25`s.

You tagged this with `[mysql]`; if that is involved, please do a `SELECT HEX(...)` to see if the "double-encoding" happened when *inserting* into the database.